# How weblogic support multi threading application

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic

Currently i have a multi-threading java application which use 3 thread deployed in weblogic server 11g. But when the application is running i can see only 1 running Execute Thread from weblogic console .

[image]

Can anyone explain if there is any difference between my application thread and Execute thread in weblogic ?

Answer (score 1):

The weblogic console only shows threads that it (the weblogic server) created and therefore monitors. Your application threads are probably started like this: `new Thread(new MyThreadClass())).start()`, this does not use any weblogic API and are unknown to it.

You can read more about how weblogic 12 handles threads here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/topics.htm#WLPRG386